# Multiple increments in table

Tags: database-design, php

Let's say I have a table which stores different bills.

There are multiple departments using this database and every department  needs to use their own incremental numbering for the bills.

I do not want to use multiple tables, so I have an issue what the best method for this issue is.

I have come up with an suggestion by myself, but I think this is not a good solution. Namely keep a column `DepartmentBillId` and keep track of the numbering in PHP (this will be the easiest way though, but I have multiple users so this could actually cause conflicts).

I hope somebody can guide me in the best direction!

Comment: Check the question and my answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119183/auto-increment-a-column-that-is-not-unique/119190#119190) if it is what you have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the way to go is that you create a pre-insert trigger that will set the `BILL_ID` for that department when no `BILL_ID` was given. To get the next `BILL_ID` you could use a table that holds the last `BILL_ID` per department. An other way is to get the `MAX(BILL_ID)` for that department and add 1 to it. When you work with multiple users then the first solution is better and faster. The primary key for the `BILLS` table would be `DEPARTMENT_ID, BILL_ID` and perhaps even `YEAR` if you need to start at 1 when the new year starts.

Comment: Exactly what we are doing for a similar problem